# Wrong layout when adding button to different images

Tags: html, css

I want to add button to images (display a button on top of an image with center position). Thing goes well if the image is 100% width. But if it's 50% width, the button isn't centered on top of the image.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Button on Image</h2>
<p>Add a button to an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width: 200px; float:left;margin-left:15%">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Wrong output:
[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIHMO.png)

Thank you so so much!!

Comment: The button position is with respect to the container, not the image. Instead, resize the container div.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you style it like this. The container is dimensioned by the image size, and the button is positioned absolutely relative to the container at 50% horizontally and vertically by the half of its own dimensions, then translated leftwards and upwards by the half of the button's dimensions (`-50%, -50%`).

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container>img {
  display: block;
}

.container>button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.cinematheque.fr/cache/media/01-films/la_maison_du_docteur-e/s,725-75eea0.jpg">
  <button>Button</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img style="width: 200px;" src="https://www.cinematheque.fr/cache/media/01-films/la_maison_du_docteur-e/s,725-75eea0.jpg">
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks you so much. Very appreciate

Answer (score 0):

The button will stay in the center of `container` because the `absolute` position looks for nearest `relative` element.

now you have two options:
1- set image in center of `container` by adding a `margin-left:25%`

2- set container width to `50%` instead of image width

look at this please :

```
  <h2>Button on Image</h2>
  <p>Add a button to an image:</p>

  <div class="container">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/600" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
     <button class="btn">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="Snow" style="width:50%; margin-left:25%;">
     <button class="btn">Button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="width:50%">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="Snow" style="">
     <button class="btn">Button</button>
  </div>
```

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/mohammad7484/pen/zYKwYMW)

Comment: Thanks you so much. Very appreciate